# How to replace values in dataframe based on a second dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df1 with multiple columns, each column representing a species name (sp1, sp2, sp3, ...).

```
df1

  sp1   sp2   sp3    sp4 
  NA    NA    r1      r1
  NA    NA    1       3
  NA    5     NA      NA
  m4    NA    NA      m2
```

I would like to replace each value in df1 with values based on a second dataframe, df2. Here, the values in df1 should match df2$scale_nr, and replaced by `df2$percentage`. Thus, the result should be so that I have my values in `df1` based on `$percentage` in `df2`.

```
df2

scale_nr   percentage
r1          1
p1          1
a1          1
m1          1
r2          2
p2          2
a2          2
m2          2
1           10
2           20
3           30
4           40
...
```

Then after replacement df1 should look like

```
df1

  sp1   sp2   sp3    sp4
  NA    NA    1       1
  NA    NA    10      30
  NA    50    NA      NA
  4     NA    NA      2
```

I tried this:

```
df2$percentage[match(df1$sp1, df2$scale_nr)] # this one works for one column
```

which works for one column, I know I should be able to do this over all columns easily, but somehow I can't figure it out.

I know I could do it by 'hand', like

```
df[df == 'Old Value'] <- 'New value'
```

but this seems highly inefficient because I have 40 different values that need to be replaced.

Can someone please help me with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` on the frame to iterate the same thing over multiple columns.

```r
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(z) df2$percentage[match(z, df2$scale_nr)])
df1
#   sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
# 1  NA  NA   1   1
# 2  NA  NA  10  30
# 3  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4  NA  NA  NA   2
```

The missing values are likely because of the truncated `df2` in the sample data.

If you want the option to preserve the previous value if not found in `df2`, then you can modify that slightly:

```r
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(z) {
  newval <- df2$percentage[match(z, df2$scale_nr)]
  ifelse(is.na(newval), z, newval)
})
df1
#    sp1 sp2  sp3  sp4
# 1 <NA>  NA    1    1
# 2 <NA>  NA   10   30
# 3 <NA>   5 <NA> <NA>
# 4   m4  NA <NA>    2
```

FYI, the reassignment into `df1[] <-` is important, in constrast with `df1 <-`. The difference is that `lapply` is going to return a list`, so if you use` df1 <-`then`df1`will no longer be a`data.frame`. Using` df[] <-`, you are telling it to replace the contents of the columns without changing the overall class of` df1`.

If you need to do this on only a subset of columns, that's easy:

```r
df1[1:3] <- lapply(df[1:3], ...)`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Especially the ```df[] ``` <- I was not aware of and did the trick